# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la codificación de una cadena en Java/Android para mostrar acentos y caracteres especiales?

Tags: java, android, string, volley

Estoy haciendo una prueba con código que viene del servidor, el cual trae los acentos con el carácter �.

Los datos son traídos a través de Volley.

Por ejemplo:

```
Anastasio Sina�ta
Andr�s
Andr�s Kim Taegon
Anselmo
Anselmo de Havelberg
Antonio
Antonio Mar�a Claret
Antonio Royo Mar�n
Asterio de Amasea
Atanasio
Autor An�nimo
Autor Antiguo
Autor Contempor�neo
Autor del Siglo II
```

Sé que si en mi servidor establezco un encabezado adecuado este problema se resuelve, pero estaba tratando de buscar una solución a una pregunta donde no se tenía control del lado del servidor. Los datos vienen así y punto, hay que convertirlos del lado de Java/Android.

He tratado con estas opciones:

- `String newString = new String(response.getBytes(), "UTF-8");`
- `String newString = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`

No funciona. En el primer caso me cambia el carácter inspector por `?1/2` y en el segundo me lo cambia por `?`.

**¿Cómo podría entonces mostrar los acentos en esta cadena? ¿Hay alguna forma de saber en qué está codificada una cadena?**

**¿Tiene Volley en sí misma alguna forma de tratar esto?**

He intentando enviar un encabezado como este en la petición:

```
params.put("Content-Type" ,"text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

El encabezado llega, lo he comprobado, pero no funciona.

También he puesto esto a la petición Volley y nada:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
}
```

Comment: @abrahamhs por favor lee bien la pregunta, estamos ante un caso en el que es imposible establecer encabezados del lado del servidor porque no se tiene acceso a ese código. No estoy intentando reinventar la rueda, sino en palear la situación del lado de Android porque el servidor manda los datos así (API de terceros, hosting gratuito...) y no se tiene privilegios para modificar el código de servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que la información esta codificada en "ISO-8859-1"

En lugar de :

```
 String newString = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Para que se desplieguen correctamente los datos podrías usar:

```
String newString = new String(response, "ISO-8859-1");
```

---

ejemplo:

```
String string = "aáeéiíoóuúñoña";
response = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
```

en este punto el valor de `response` es : a�e�i�o�u��o�a

ahora obtenemos la representación string con el charset "ISO-8859-1":

```
  String respuesta = new String(response, "ISO-8859-1");
```

se obtiene como valor de `respuesta` : `aáeéiíoóuúñoña`

Comment: Jorge no me permite usar: `String repuesta = new String(response, "ISO-8859-1");` Da el error: *`Cannot resolve constructor`*

Comment: Que raro, response es en verdad un arreglo de bytes?  este es el constructor : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String) obviamente debes agregar manejo de la excepcion.

Comment: Jorge, el error *`Cannot resolve constructor`*  lo he corregido haciendo esto: `byte [] bytesResponse = response.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); String newString = new String(bytesResponse,"ISO-8859-1");` Pero no funciona, cambia el carácter inspector por `?`. El código está dentro de un `try... catch`, muestro el texto tanto en el logcat como en un  TextView y nada de nada.